# SyntaxError: invalid syntax when if statement

Tags: python-3.x

I'm newbie and I'm beginning in programming with Python. I was doing a simple code, but I don't know why it returns me  a syntax error.

Here the code:

```
contador = 1
aprobados = 0
suspendidos = 0


numero_alumnos = int(input('cuando alumnos tienes?:'))

while contador <= numero_alumnos:

    nota = int(input(f'que nota quieres ponerle al \"alumno{contador}\" ?:')

    if nota >= 5:
        aprobados += 1
    else:
        suspendidos += 1

    contador += 1

print(f'alumnos aprobados': {aprobados})
print(f'alumnos suspendidos': {suspendidos})
```

And here the message from the console:

````
    if nota >= 5:
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax```
````

Comment: Your nota variable needs another )

Comment: `int(input(f'que nota quieres ponerle al \"alumno{contador}\" ?:')`   += `)`

Answer (score 1):

You're forgetting a closing `)` on the line above it
`int(input(f'que nota quieres ponerle al \"alumno{contador}\" ?:'))`